# Get pixels and colours from NSImage

Tags: cocoa, nsimage

I have created an NSImage object, and ideally would like to determine how many of each pixels colour it contains. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest creating your own [bitmap context](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/), wrapping it in a [graphics context](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSGraphicsContext_Class/) and setting that as the current context, [telling the image to draw itself](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:), and then accessing the pixel data behind the bitmap context directly.

This will be more code, but will save you both a trip through a TIFF representation and the creation of thousands or millions of NSColor objects. If you're working with images of any appreciable size, these expenses will add up quickly.

Comment: For new lazy readers: This solution is **Implemented** in @gavinb's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43232455/2000566).

Comment: The documentation you linked are 404s. This is no longer a workable answer.

Answer (score 12):

This code renders the `NSImage` into a `CGBitmapContext`:

```
- (void)updateImageData {

    if (!_image)
        return;

    // Dimensions - source image determines context size

    NSSize imageSize = _image.size;
    NSRect imageRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);

    // Create a context to hold the image data

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);

    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                             imageSize.width,
                                             imageSize.height,
                                             8,
                                             0,
                                             colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    // Wrap graphics context

    NSGraphicsContext* gctx = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithCGContext:ctx flipped:NO];

    // Make our bitmap context current and render the NSImage into it

    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:gctx];
    [_image drawInRect:imageRect];

    // Calculate the histogram

    [self computeHistogramFromBitmap:ctx];

    // Clean up

    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:nil];
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```

Given a bitmap context, we can access the raw image data directly, and compute the histograms for each colour channel:

```
- (void)computeHistogramFromBitmap:(CGContextRef)bitmap {

    // NB: Assumes RGBA 8bpp

    size_t width = CGBitmapContextGetWidth(bitmap);
    size_t height = CGBitmapContextGetHeight(bitmap);

    uint32_t* pixel = (uint32_t*)CGBitmapContextGetData(bitmap);

    for (unsigned y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (unsigned x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            uint32_t rgba = *pixel;

            // Extract colour components
            uint8_t red   = (rgba & 0x000000ff) >> 0;
            uint8_t green = (rgba & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            uint8_t blue  = (rgba & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;

            // Accumulate each colour
            _histogram[kRedChannel][red]++;
            _histogram[kGreenChannel][green]++;
            _histogram[kBlueChannel][blue]++;

            // Next pixel!
            pixel++;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

I've published a complete project, a Cocoa sample app, which includes the above.

- https://github.com/gavinb/CocoaImageHistogram.git

Answer (score 9):

Get an [`NSBitmapImageRep`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from your `NSImage`. Then you can get access to the pixels.

```
NSImage* img = ...;
NSBitmapImageRep* raw_img = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[img TIFFRepresentation]];
NSColor* color = [raw_img colorAtX:0 y:0];
```

Comment: This is a very expensive approach, as `colorAtX:y:` will involve creating an `NSColor` instance for each pixel, as Peter Hosey notes.  It is much more efficient to get the raw data buffer and walk through using pointers to calculate the histogram.

Comment: Hi gavinb, do you have any directions (get the raw data buffer and walk through using pointers) on this one? Thank you!

Comment: @clearlight Well I didn't realise I was keeping anyone in suspense. I wrote a sample app which does just what is described above, and added the code in an answer to this question. I've published it on github too. Enjoy!

Comment: @clearlight See my new answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/43232455/172642 - this basically implements what @Peter Hosey describes in his answer. Using the `NSColor colorAtX:y` is definitely not how this should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Look for "histogram" in the Core Image documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Using `colorAtX` with `NSBitmapImageRep` does not always lead to the exact correct color.

I managed to get the correct color with this simple code:

```
[yourImage lockFocus]; // yourImage is just your NSImage variable
NSColor *pixelColor = NSReadPixel(NSMakePoint(1, 1)); // Or another point
[yourImage unlockFocus];
```

Answer (score 1):

This maybe a more streamlined approach for some and reduce complexity of dropping into memory management.

https://github.com/koher/EasyImagy

Code sample
https://github.com/koher/EasyImagyCameraSample

```
import EasyImagy

let image = Image<RGBA<UInt8>>(nsImage: "test.png") // N.B. init with nsImage 

print(image[x, y])
image[x, y] = RGBA(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 127)
image[x, y] = RGBA(0xFF00007F) // red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 127

// Iterates over all pixels
for pixel in image {
    // ...
}



//// Gets a pixel by subscripts Gets a pixel by  
let pixel = image[x, y]
// Sets a pixel by subscripts
image[x, y] = RGBA(0xFF0000FF)
image[x, y].alpha = 127
// Safe get for a pixel
if let pixel = image.pixelAt(x: x, y: y) {
    print(pixel.red)
    print(pixel.green)
    print(pixel.blue)
    print(pixel.alpha)

    print(pixel.gray) // (red + green + blue) / 3
    print(pixel) // formatted like "#FF0000FF"
} else {
    // `pixel` is safe: `nil` is returned when out of bounds
    print("Out of bounds")
}
```