# cocoa: Read pixel color of NSImage

Tags: cocoa, nsimage, nscolor, nsbitmapimagerep

I have an `NSImage`. I would like to read the `NSColor` for a pixel at some x and y. Xcode seems to thing that there is a `colorAtX:y:` method on `NSImage`, but this causes a crash saying that there is no such method for NSImage. I have seen some examples where you create an `NSBitmapImageRep` and call the same method on that, but I have not been able to successfully convert my NSImage to an `NSBitmapImageRep`. The pixels on the `NSBitmapImageRep` are different for some reason.

There must be a simple way to do this. It cannot be this complicated.

Comment: In what way are the "pixels on the NSBitmapImageRep" different? I have done it that way before and gotten good results.

Comment: See Rob Keniger's answer below. The anchor point (origin) of NSImage is top-left, and NSBitmapImageRep is bottom-left. When you convert from one to the other, the image coordinates are flipped vertically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get pixels and colours from NSImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994082/get-pixels-and-colours-from-nsimage)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without seeing your code it's difficult to know what's going wrong.

You can draw the image to an `NSBitmapImageRep` using the `initWithData:` method and pass in the image's `TIFFRepresentation`.

You can then get the pixel value using the method `colorAtX:y:`, which is a method of `NSBitmapImageRep`, not `NSImage`:

```
NSBitmapImageRep* imageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:[yourImage TIFFRepresentation]];
NSSize imageSize = [yourImage size];
CGFloat y = imageSize.height - 100.0;
NSColor* color = [imageRep colorAtX:100.0 y:y];
[imageRep release];
```

Note that you must make an adjustment for the `y` value because the `colorAtX:y` method uses a coordinate system that starts in the top left of the image, whereas the `NSImage` coordinate system starts at the bottom left.

Alternatively, if the pixel is visible on-screen then you can use the [`NSReadPixel()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000695-SW38) function to get the color of a pixel in the current coordinate system.

Comment: Ok so I am trying it this way, but something seems off. Is the coordinate system of an NSBitmapImageRep different than an NSImage? Everything seems to be flipped vertically. It would seem that NSImage is being drawn from the bottom left (like view's are by default) and the NSBitmapImageRep is drawing from the top left (thus flipping the image). I'm not actually drawing to the screen, so I can't see.

Comment: It appears you are correct, the coordinates are flipped. I've added code to account for that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rob. I ran into another road block while editing the image, and found that I had to create a new NSImage instance from the altered NSBitmapImageRep. So my code ended up being along the lines of create NSBitmapImageRep from NSImage, read pixels, change pixels, create NSImage from altered NSBitmapImageRep, assign new NSImage to view. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note that you might want to use imageRep.pixelsWide and imageRep.pixelsHigh, as these are resolution independent. When using the size as in this example it doesn't necessarily correspond to the pixels you are trying to read.

Comment: Thanks @NathanS. -- I just got burned by that :)

Answer (score 1):

Function `colorAtX` of `NSBitmapImageRep` seems not to use the device color space, which may lead to color values that are slightly different from what you actually see. Use this code to get the correct color in the current device color space:

```
[yourImage lockFocus]; // yourImage is just your NSImage variable
NSColor *pixelColor = NSReadPixel(NSMakePoint(1, 1)); // Or another point
[yourImage unlockFocus];
```

Comment: Could you give a little more info? What does 'not always lead to the exact correct color' mean?

Comment: @walteronassis: I changed my answer a bit